# How to change the flag pictures XFCE Keyboard Layouts applet uses for its indication?

Tags: xfce, theme, icons, xkb

XFCE Keyboard Layouts panel applet offers to use either textual or graphical indications. But the font used for textual indication is too small and the flag icons used for graphical are too blowzy. How can I set up another flags set?

Comment: Thinking about it, rather than hacking up a solution, it might be advisable to [file a bug report.](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/)

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked in `/usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/`?  I *guess* changing these files could do the trick.

Comment: 10 years later, I can confirm it does the trick :) These are .svg files, so editable with any text editor, too.